# Shell show same files in the same path?

Tags: shell

I got two `output` folders when I type `ls -l` on shell.

```
MyBookLive:~/download/# ls -l
drwxrwxrw- 4 root root    65536 2013-12-20 12:33 output
drwxrwxrw- 3 root root    65536 2013-12-20 12:33 output
```

And I am sure there is no spaces in filename, because when I hit `tab` key, it shows:

```
MyBookLive:~/download/# ls -l output
output/  output/
```

Why? Thanks.

Comment: 'x', backspace, 'o', 'u', 't', 'p', 'u', 't'? There are more ways of hiding characters in a name than using trailing spaces. Study the output of `ls | od -c` or something similar.

Comment: Check `ls | od -c` or something like that to see if there are any hidden chars in the file names. But if the names really are identical, you may have file system corruption. Try running `fsck` on your file system (you may need to be in single user mode).

Comment: Thanks, I got some codes: '302 201  ' after one of `output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second "output" has character 129 after the last "t".

Try this in your browser's console, copying the "output/  output/" string from your question.

```
"output/  output/".split('').forEach(function(x){console.log(x, x.charCodeAt(0))})
```

Comment: Thanks. Seams 129 don't mean anything as a ascii code.